# Error not triggered on wrong RPC

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

I have a weird behavior when I call a function (mint) with a wrong RPC...First of all let me show you a function triggering properly an error in my code:

```
const fetchBalance = (addressTemp) => {
    web3.eth
      .getBalance(addressTemp)
      .then((result) => {
        setBalance(web3.utils.fromWei(bal));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

this throw the error (as it should):

> RPC Error: [-32603] Internal error: Network Error

Now on the other hand, my Mint call, simply get stuck and do nothing:

```
let { transactionHash } = await contractAudio.methods
      .mint(
        _user.publicAddress,
      )
      .send({ from: _user.publicAddress })
      .then(function (transactionHash) {
        console.log(`transactionHash: ${transactionHash}`);
      })
      .then(function (receipt) {
        console.log(receipt);       
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error}`);
      });
```

Would you know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

it is now working as expected, I guess it was an error/slowdown on Mumbai